# Constrain parameter between -1 and 1 in R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

How would I restrict variable x over [-1, 1] when using the function optim (method = BFGS)?  Such as restricting a variable between [0,1] would be

```
1 / (1 + exp(-variable))
```

or

```
exp(variable)/(1+exp(variable))
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: `(variable^2 - 1 )   / (variable^2 + 1)` can be another option.

Comment: @MKR thank you very much!  Simple and straightforward

Comment: Not very elegant so I won't put it as an answer but ... `ifelse(abs(x) <= 1, your_function(x), Inf)`

Comment: And note that the restrictions you give actually restrict to (0,1) so do you want [-1, 1] or would (-1, 1) be fine for your purposes?

Comment: Why not use L-BFGS-B method, which has bounded parameters?